# Проблема с SMPP, ошибка ESME_RALYBND

Tags: smpp

Здравствуйте, возникла такая проблема. SMPP при попытке подключения сообщает command_status: 5, она же ESME_RALYBND. Грубо говоря сервер отвечает что соединение уже создано. На команды unbind я получаю ответ command_status: 4.

Собственно есть ли способ подключиться к уже созданной сессии или закрыть имеющуюся?

Comment: Вы используете какую-то библиотеку для работы  по SMPP или сами открываете TCP соединение с сервером и шлёте ему вручную созданные PDU? Если да, как вы формируете PDU для команды bind? Есть ли SMPP клиенты успешно работающие с этим же сервером? Если да, то имеет смысл сравнить сетевой дамп их обмена с сервером с дампом обмена с сервером вашей программы.

Comment: Я использую библиотеку для node.js https://github.com/farhadi/node-smpp
Есть еще пара других smpp серверов с ними все нормально, там такой проблемы нет, проблема возникла только с этим мегафоновским smpp сервером. Для текущего smpp сервера у меня есть данные только одного клиента.
В начале сессиия успешно создавалась, но на submit_sm я получал command_status 1313, написал им, они что то поменяли и начались  проблемы с сессией.

Comment: На запрос bind_transceiver я получаю
{ command_length: 22,
  command_id: 2147483657,
  command_status: 5,
  sequence_number: 2,
  command: 'bind_transceiver_resp',
  system_id: '',
  sc_interface_version: 52 }

На запрос unbind я получаю
{ command_length: 16,
  command_id: 2147483654,
  command_status: 4,
  sequence_number: 1,
  command: 'unbind_resp' }

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9acdf8ee1066cbde5e7a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в том, что у меня в фоне запускался еще один экземпляр клиентского приложения, который и занимал соединение. Вот так как то...